# Как получить значений из объекта в java

Tags: java

Как получить самую старую книгу?

```
public static void addBooks() {

        ListBook book1 = new ListBook("Уотерс Сара", "Дорогие гости", 2018);
        ListBook book2 = new ListBook("Пелевин Виктор", "Тайные виды на гору Фудзи", 2017);
        ListBook book3 = new ListBook("Сейгер Райли", "Последние Девушки", 2019);
```

Comment: понимаю что надо в цикле пройтись по всем книгам и сравнить их год издания, книга с наименьшим значением года издания будет самой старой.

Comment: но как ето можна реализовать?

Comment: сейчас ответ напишу

Comment: Реализовать проходом в цикле по книгам. В чем именно проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш `ListBook`:

```
public class ListBook {
    private String author;
    private String name;
    private int year;

    public ListBook(String author, String name, int year) {
        this.author = author;
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return this.year;
    }
}
```

В том классе, где создаете экземпляры класса напишите метод:

```
ListBook list[] = new ListBook[2];
    list[0] =  new ListBook("Уотерс Сара", "Дорогие гости", 2018);
    list[1] = new ListBook("Пелевин Виктор", "Тайные виды на гору Фудзи", 2017);
    list[2] = new ListBook("Сейгер Райли", "Последние Девушки", 2019);

    ListBookmin = list[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].getYear() < min.getYear()) {
            min = list[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(min.getYear());
```